# How to protect localStorage?

Tags: html, local-storage

My understanding is that if you clear cache in a webkit browser then this will delete all localStorage entries.

Is there any way to protect localStorage against user actions such as this?  I'd like my app to be the only thing that can delete specific localStorage entries.

I'm targetting webkit specifically - if I can't protect localStorage, what are my options (just need simple key-value pair storage.

Thanks

Comment: robertc is correct, you can't and shouldn't be able to protect it -- it's the user's machine after all.  but in terms of playing nicely with other JS code that may want to do things to localStorage, I'm proposing this: https://github.com/joelarson4/LSNS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, and if there is there shouldn't be.  Putting data on the user's hard disk which the user cannot delete is an activity more commonly associated with malware.  There have in the past been a number of class action lawsuits to do with [cookies which were impossible to delete (see the last 3 paragraphs)](http://arstechnica.com/web/news/2010/09/evercookie-escalates-the-zombie-cookie-war-by-raising-awareness.ars).